# How to influence the reponse ws-addressing action element?

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, ws-addressing

it seems that my response from a cxf implemented webservice contains a

```
<Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn://...dummy.../WebserviceResponse</Action>
```

Is there a way i can remove the urn and only keep the /WebserviceResponse or make the action empty?

```
<Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">/WebserviceResponse</Action>
```

The system that uses that uses our webservice fails on the urn on the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer via the CXF Mailinglist... All credits go to Daniel Kulp for providing the answer!

```
<quote>
```

If java first, you would need to add @Action annotations to the methods to
control the actions that are used and expected for the input and output (and
faults).

For wsdl first, you would need to add wsam:Action attributes to the
portType/operation/input and output elements. (which would result in the
above annotations being generated)

```
</quote>
```